# Conditional Probability Decomposition

Tags: probability

I've seen people decompose $p(x|z) = p(x|y)p(y|z)$ for random variables $x, y, z$. I'm not sure why this holds$-$I thought only $$p(x|z) = \sum_y p(x,y|z)=\sum_y p(x|y,z)p(y|z) = \sum_y p(x|y)p(y|z)$$
holds, assuming $x$ and $z$ are conditionally independent given $y$. What would be the exact derivation and assumptions for the first decomposition?

Comment: The equation doesn't make much sense, as $y$ is a free variable on the right-hand side but not on the left. It would require either a sum or a quantification over $y$. Perhaps said people were using a summation convention where $y$ was implicitly being summed over?

Comment: Source? $ $ $ $

Comment: Eq. 1 on page 3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.04793, and also eq. 1 on page 3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04892

Comment: Horrible notations, and absurd, these authors should learn stochastics before pretending to use the field.

Comment: There are several ways the notation can be improved to make the meaning clearer and less prone to abuse.  Often capital letters are used for random variables, which small letters indicate potential values for the random variables.  It's a reasonable question to ask about how the authors intended their expressions, but shortcuts must typically be spelled out at least once in the body of the papers where they are used.

Comment: @hardmath Not only a matter of unexplained notations, I am afraid. Actually, *with the notations intended by the authors*, the formula  $p(x|z) = p(x|y)p(y|z)$ is wrong in general.